# Embedded single table mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm facing an issue with modelling hibernate mapping. Here is what i have:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Entry {

@Id private long id;
@Embedded private Content content;
...
}

@MappedSuperclass
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="content_type")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Content {

@Column(name="content_type") private String type;
...
}

@Embeddable
@DiscriminatorValue("A")
public class AContent extends Content {
...
}

@Embeddable
@DiscriminatorValue("B")
public class BContent extends Content {
...
}
```

I'd like to have that all subclasses of Content to be mapped as embedded onto the Entry class.
In other words, in result i'd like to have one Entry table with columns from all subclasses of Content.

Currently the persisting Entry test says that:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: 
Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface:  : foo.bar.Content
```

So it seems that loading fails because instead of getting AContent it tries to instantiate abstract Content. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spec says...

*An entity may inherit from another entity class. Entities support inheritance, polymorphic associations and polymorphic queries.*

It says nothing about embeddables being inheritable and thus has no support for inheritance for them.